# Do javascript templates save server performance over php templates?

Tags: javascript, php, templates, symfony, underscore.js

So I'm trying to create a website that almost runs only on the clientside using symfony2, backbonejs and underscore.
symfony2 for the backend and backbonejs for the frontend.
Symfony2 uses twig templates which get compilled into php classes by the server.

Would it save server performance to avoid twig templates as often as possible and use javascript templates (underscore) instead? 
Or doesn't it make a difference since the templates need to be fetched from the server anyway?

Comment: If your server has to do less work if you changed the templating scheme, then yes, you'd save resources. However, the answer is hugely debatable. But as the common logic dictates, the less work there is to do - the better, therefore you save resources. Issue is, how much of the processing power actually gets allocated to PHP, if you run your entire stack on 1 server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetching a static file from the server is always going to give you better server performance than having the server process a template and return the result. The chances of that being significant are pretty low though, and you'd have to benchmark it to find out how much difference it makes.

Fetching a static template file from a server and fetching a dynamically generated data file to inject into it may or may not give you better performance then having the server insert the data into the template. You'd have to benchmark it.

Performance benefits of using client side templates almost always come from:

- Having to fetch small data files from the server instead of HTML documents
- Modifying page of an existing page instead of clearing it and loading a completely fresh one

The benefits do have to be weighed against the costs though (which are either the additional work to make the site continue to work if JS isn't available combined with the use of `pushState` and friends to have workable URLs or the fragility and search engine invisibility of a site completely dependant of JS)